# Unlocking Characters in Mario Kart 8

Tags: achievements, mario-kart-8

It seems that I unlock a character each time I win a gold cup that I didn't have before. For example, if I win the leaf cup in 150ccm for the first time, I get a new character, but if I win it in 150ccm again, I don't.

I only played 150ccm so far and got the gold cup everywhere. Now I guess I can't unlock any more characters in 150ccm. But can I unlock more characters by playing the lower difficulty, even though the cups and stars carry over to the lower ranks? Or is my only option to win 200ccm cups now? If yes, how can someone who started with 200ccm (and got all gold cups there) ever unlock every character?

It seems I did not state clear enough what I want to know, so I try again:

If I have won a gold cup in some difficulty for the first time (and unlocked a character by this), will I be able to unlock a new character by playing the same cup in an easier difficulty?

I have already tested that it is NOT possible to unlock a new character by playing the same difficulty again: I played the mushroom cup 3 times in 150ccm, every time with 60 points (=always first), but still only got ONE character unlocked.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I tested it; the answer is yes.
If you have won cup X in a harder difficulty level, and unlocked a character by it, it is possible to play the same cup X in an easier difficulty level and unlock another character.

Comment: This is exactly what your other answers are saying.

Comment: Nope, the others were giving wrong statements. They stated that it does not matter if a cup has been won before, which is definitely wrong as I already stated in the question. Thus, their answers have no use to me (or any other person interested in the question I stated) as they only show that they don't know the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mario-kart-8/Characters) wiki, you get random characters simply getting gold on **any** CC in Grand Prix mode.

Comment: At least I just noticed that winning the same gold cup several times does NOT give me a new character. Well, I guess I have to try out and win one of the easier races...

Comment: Nothing I found online specified that you could only unlock once per race track, but that would be in line with the number of tracks and everything.

Comment: Does the nonexistence of an online source have more authority than simple tests with the actual game?

Comment: I wasn't implying that at all. You asked a question, and I gave you an answer utilizing the resources available. At this point all you can do is do what you just said. Test and validate or refute.

Answer (score 2):

New characters are unlocked at random for each cup you complete, in any engine class. The exception is the Mii character, who is unlocked when you get the gold trophy in every cup in a single engine class. There are a total of 14 unlockable characters, including the Mii.